# What is memmap and how do you use it?

Tags: kernel, hardware

I have a faulty memory with a consistent offset, and according to UnixSE, I could use memmap to solve this problem by having the kernel avoiding this certain offset via memmap:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75059/how-to-blacklist-a-correct-bad-ram-sector-according-to-memtest86-error-indicati

What exactly is memmap, where do I put
`memmap=10M$800M` in? Is memmap a unix utility I have to install or is it in a config file somewhere in Ubuntu?